# How to create lines without using an image

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, css-shapes

I'm trying to create the diagram below (without ASCII chars obviously and as solid lines) without using images. How would I go about it? I was thinking of canvas, or CSS3 unless there's something better.

```
 \                       /
  \                     /
   ---------------------
  /                     \
 /                       \
```

Comment: Depends what you want to do with it. As it stands, this question is too broad to answer properly. Also, SVG may be a good option.

Comment: I just want to have a number on the top and bottom of the horizontal line and then on the ends of the diagram as well.

Comment: Both Canvas & SVG will easily draw the lines plus textual numbers you need.

Comment: @Catfish. You ask a good question but questions with the words "best/easiest" are doomed to be closed. Ironically, the current close votes are for "too broad" rather than "opinion based" while your question is extremely well and narrowly defined. I've edited your question to remove those close-vote-attracting words. BTW, in canvas check out the `moveTo` & `lineTo` commands. In SVG, check out the path sub-element  using the `M or m` & `L or l` commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways in which the effect provided in question could be achieved and snippets for a few of them is provided below. Each have their own merits and demerits and so choose one of them depending on what your requirements are.

**Using CSS Transforms:**

We can use CSS perspective transforms with two pseudo-elements each of which are roughly 50% of the parent's height. The pseudo-elements are positioned absolutely with respect to the parent and the borders on them produce the lines. (The method used for positioning the `span` are just random and you can use any method which you feel comfortable with.)

Perspective transforms can be very tricky to handle when it comes to designing responsive shapes. As the container's dimensions change we would have to modify `margin`. Else part of the shape would go out of view. It is pretty difficult to what should be the margin value at run-time.

```css
.shape{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.shape:after, .shape:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0px;
  height: calc(50% - 1px);
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
}
.shape:before{
  top: 0;
  border-width: 0px 2px 1px 2px;
  transform: perspective(50px) rotateX(-10deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  }
.shape:after{
  bottom: 0;
  border-width: 1px 2px 0px 2px;  
  transform: perspective(50px) rotateX(10deg);
  transform-origin: top;  
}
span{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
span:nth-child(1){
  left: 50%;
}
span:nth-child(2){
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
span:nth-child(3){
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-150%);
}
span:nth-child(4){
  right: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(200%);  
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
</div>
```

**Using SVG:**

With SVG, we can draw a `path` using the moveTo (`M`) and line (`L`) commands to produce the lines. The SVG drawing commands used in the snippet are very simple and self explanatory. We just move to a point (represented by X and Y coordinates) and then draw lines from that point to other specified points. Here again, the SVG is positioned absolutely with respect to the parent.

SVG is designed to be responsive by default and can adapt well even if the container's dimensions change. The one main thing to note is that the path's stroke will also scale. Because of this, when the height and width of the container changes without maintaining the original ratio (that is, say the height alone increases) then some parts of the stroke become thicker than the rest (that is, if the height alone changes then the horizontal line gets thicker). This can be addressed by adding the attribute `vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'` but this is not supported by IE.

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
span:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 50%;
}
span:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
span:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
span:nth-of-type(4) {
  right: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 200 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <path d='M0,0 L20,50 0,100 20,50 180,50 200,0 180,50 200,100' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke' />
  </svg>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
</div>
```

**Using Canvas:**

Canvas drawing commands are pretty similar to the SVG ones and here again we can draw a `path` using the `moveTo` and `lineTo` commands to produce the lines. We just move to a point (represented by X and Y coordinates) and then draw lines from that point to other specified points. Here again, the Canvas is positioned absolutely with respect to the parent.

Canvas drawings are raster based (unlike SVG which is vector based) and so it is not responsive by default. When scaled, Canvas drawings get blurred (pixelated) and would require repainting whenever container dimensions change. This makes it not very good for use when the container's dimensions aren't fixed.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  ctx.lineWidth = '2';
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(20,50);
  ctx.lineTo(0,100);
  ctx.lineTo(20,50);
  ctx.lineTo(180,50);
  ctx.lineTo(200,0);
  ctx.lineTo(180,50);
  ctx.lineTo(200,100);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}
canvas{
  position: absolute;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
span:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 50%;
}
span:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
span:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
span:nth-of-type(4) {
  right: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'>
  <canvas id='canvas' height='100px' width='200px'></canvas>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the shape is just for "decoration" you could always use the border trick with just CSS3.

```
#pentagon {
    position: relative;
    width: 54px;
    border-width: 50px 18px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #1abc9c transparent;
}

#pentagon_two{
    position: relative;
    width: 54px;
    border-width: 50px 18px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #1abc9c transparent;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxLeguLt/)